# Can we get all user count (Audiences>All Users) through firebase remote config conditional parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I have configured my app with Firebase Analytics and also has Remote Config key/value to control some data.
But, I want to show total user count in the app where I don't manage any database. So is it possible to read analytics data/user property and get all user count through remote config condition?

Refer image to see user count which I want to show in the app.

[image]